# Dump postgresql databases source one has encoding 'C.UTF-8' and destination one has encoding 'en_US.UTF-8'

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, psql

Trying to dump source database has encoding "C.UTF-8" to destination database has encoding "en_US.UTF-8" as the following command:

```
pg_dump -C --no-acl --no-owner -h HOST_SOURCE -U Admin -p 5432 SOURCE_DB | psql -h HOST_DESTINATION -U Admin -p 5432 DESTINATION_DB
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "C.UTF-8"
\connect: FATAL:  database "SOURCE_DB" does not exist
```

How can I ignore the encoding on pg_dump command?

Comment: Omit the `-C` option and create the destination database first.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe! it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on comment @LaurenzAlbe, when I removed -C option, the command working fine!

```
pg_dump --no-acl --no-owner -h HOST_SOURCE -U Admin -p 5432 SOURCE_DB | psql -h HOST_DESTINATION -U Admin -p 5432 DESTINATION_DB
```